# Moongoose update subdocument array object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update one object of an subdoc array with findByIdAndUpdate by parent id and subdoc object id. When executing this code, I got this error:

```
The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
```

When I use updateOne with filter parameter, it works. But I would like to get the updated document to return as json for rest api.

Is there any way to get the updated document?

My Code:

```
Subject.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.subjectId, "bookmarks._id": req.params.bookmarkId },
  {
    $set: {
      "bookmarks.$.uri": req.body.uri
    }
  },
  { new: true }
)
```

Schema:

```
{
    "_id": "5e7fbfc05ff6be1446b51af7",
    "user_id": "5e7e68c3fd5e9404ce6a14a3",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "date": "2020-03-28T21:21:04.434Z",
    "bookmarks": [
        {
            "date": "2020-03-28T21:21:20.806Z",
            "_id": "5e7fbfd05ff6be1446b51afa",
            "uri": "lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-03-28T21:21:21.433Z",
            "_id": "5e7fbfd15ff6be1446b51afb",
            "uri": "lorem ipsum"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [.findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html) :

As your `req.params.subjectId` and `req.params.bookmarkId` are strings & respective fields in your DB will be of type `ObjectId()` - So convert strings to ObjectId() using below code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.subjectId);
const bookmarkId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.bookmarkId);

Subject.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: _id, "bookmarks._id": bookmarkId },
  {
    $set: {
      "bookmarks.$.uri": 'new new'
    }
  },
  { new: true }
)
```

Your issue should be mongoose's `.findByIdAndUpdate()` does takes in just one string value & internally converts it into `{_id : ObjectId(req.params.subjectId)}` to use `.findOneAndUpdate()`, it's just kind of wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. It is also working with strings, but to be safe, I adopt your idea of converting the strings for the query into Object Ids. :)

Comment: @mnlfischer : no you don’t have to necessarily convert from string to ObjectId() if your database has those fields as strings, conversion is all about to make sure types do match..

Comment: After some research I will use mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(subjectId) to check if the passed parameter is a valid object id. I dont define an id explicit, so I get a auto generated object id for every subject. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!